# Something rarely in Pig, cloudera quickstart

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera

I do not understand because when I run a  pig script in the editor,
 a workflow is created in ozzie and also three jobs like image , rather than simply running the script like in hive.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqjvZ.png)

```
entrada = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Divisas/Barril-WTI.csv' using PigStorage (',') AS (Fecha:chararray, Valor: float);
entrada_sin_cabecera = filter entrada by Fecha != 'Date';
orden = order entrada_sin_cabecera by Valor;
dump orden;
```

Also gives me the following error when running: `pig -f WTI.pig`

### Error before Pig is launched

> ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File WTI.pig does not exist
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File WTI.pig does not exist    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:424)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFilesInternal(FileLocalizer.java:747)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFile(FileLocalizer.java:688)
>     at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:424)   at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: It would appear that the file is not where you are telling pig it is. Are you running this command from the master node? Does WTI.pig exist in the directory you are running the pig command from?

Comment: Oh God WTI.pig is in another directory i am running pig command.  But they mean these three executions should not be only one to be a script?